# Python Flask Api - image upload & display url

Tags: ubuntu, flask

Basically I'm working in php laravel.

I've just started to work with Flask.
I'm developing API in Flask.
I'm trying to upload image file from Api to the Ubuntu server.
Also I wanted to share image url.

Following code is working locally but not able to retrieve image from URL.
Same code is working in ubuntu but image is not getting stored in said location.
I'm thinking I'm not giving proper path.

```
    file = request.files['file']
    file_name = str(current_user.id) +".jpg"
    file.save(os.path.join("static/corporate_employee_images/", file_name))
```

I tried to store image content in database and retrieve but that too isn't working.getting read_image not found error.

I just wanted to upload image and return its url.
In above case

http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/corporate_employee_images/10.jpg

How can I achieve this.

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I actually tried all possible way which I have I'll share code after finishing food.code working locally but not on Ubuntu.

Comment: And How should people trying to answer your question know what you tried?

Comment: Sorry. I'll share my code and my findings

Comment: That would be very helpful

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So right now you're saving the file in the current working directory, which does not have to be the same as the app folder.

So you need to save the file in the right folder, you also need to take into account the location of your flask app.

So change:

```
file.save(os.path.join("static/corporate_employee_images/", file_name))
```

to:

```
file.save(os.path.join(app.root_path, "static/corporate_employee_images/", file_name))
```

Comment: Thanks. And how can I access it?
I meant URL

Comment: `url_for('static', filename="static/corporate_employee_images/" + file_name)`

Comment: This is for html or for api? I mean I'm returning response in json. This will work?
{
    "data": [
        {
            "activities": 3,
            "email_id": "",
            "entity_name": "",
            "hours": 5,
            "hours_percentag": 15,
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/corporate_employee_images/10.jpg",
            "interest": "Mumbai",
            "job_information": "hero",
            "level": "novice",
            "location": "Mumbai",
            "organizations": 2,
        }
    ],
    "status": "success"
}

Comment: It shouldn't matter since it's a relative path anyways. It just returns `static/corporate_employee_images/10.jpg`. You can then add the start of the url in js.

Comment: Its purely Api, No Html,js used.

Comment: So you also need the `www.arrstarst.com/` part in front of the url? Then do: `request.url_root + url_for('static', filename="static/corporate_employee_images/" + file_name)`

Comment: yes I just wanted to store complete url in database and in response I pass url.
here my query is will I get file on 127.0.0.1:5000/static/corporate_employee_images/10.jpg OR 127.0.0.1:5000/corporate_employee_images/10.jpg

Comment: The first one. Because `corporate_employee_images` is not a flask route, but `static` is.

Comment: my static folder is not inside app.
https://ibb.co/PcBb3xj

Currently path becoming         <title>FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\projects\\sg-projects\\proj1\\\app\\static\\corporate_employee_images\\156.jpg' // Werkzeug Debugger</title>

Comment: hey thanks your solution worked, atleast I'm able to view in local. But still its not working on ubuntu.,.,.giving permission error. Any suggestion on that @Joost

 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Comment: That's somewhat good news I guess. Just make your static folder readable for everyone using chmod then, maybe that solves it.

Comment: I gave 777. to static folder but still no luck

Comment: Thanks Joost, In understand the logic, however server issue was not solved and I needed to submit my app so I store image in database and mobile developer will do further.